# Text input combined with drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a simple shopping list. I want to have a text input to say what the item is and then followed by a drop down box to show what section of the shop it is in. When these 2 parts are filled in I want the text to be added as an li in the relevant ul (based on the section of the shop that it's in). Here's my html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/shoppingList.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Shopping List</h1>


    <input type="text" placeholder="Type Shopping Item Here">
    <select id="aisle">
        <option value="">Please choose a section</option>
        <option value="fruitAndVeg">Fruit and Veg</option>
        <option value="meatFridge">Meat Fridge</option>
        <option value="deliCounter">Deli Counter</option>
        <option value="dairy">Dairy</option>
    </select>

    <ul id="fruitAndVeg">
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Pear</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="meatFridge">
        <li>Sausage</li>
        <li>Chicken</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="deliCounter">
        <li>Ham</li>
        <li>Cheese</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="dairy">
        <li>Milk</li>
        <li>Yoghurt</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="other">
        <li>Sweets</li>
        <li>Chocolate</li>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/shoppingList.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can add an li to one of the uls using jQuery but how do I add it to the correct ul based on the value of the dropdown? here's my jQuery so far

```
    $("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(event.which === 13){
        $(this).val("");
        $("#fruitAndVeg").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      var option = $("#aisle").val()
      if(event.which === 13){
          $(this).val("");
          $("#" + option).append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
      } 
});`
```

Comment: Brilliant. This worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this.

```
   if(event.which === 13)
{ 
     var ulId = $('#aisle').val();
     $(ulId).append( "<li>" + value + "</li>" );
     $(this).val("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
   $("#"+value).append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
```

Comment: Try adding some explanation, otherwise your code only answer will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for the `change` event on your `select` in order to use both the selected value and the `input` value to append to the right list. For example:

```js
const item = $('input');
const aisle = $('#aisle');
aisle.change(() => {
  const value = item.val();
  if (value) {
    $('#' + aisle.val()).append(`<li>${value}</li>`);
    item.val(''); // reset input
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Shopping Item Here">
<select id="aisle">
  <option value="">Please choose a section</option>
  <option value="fruitAndVeg">Fruit and Veg</option>
  <option value="meatFridge">Meat Fridge</option>
  <option value="deliCounter">Deli Counter</option>
  <option value="dairy">Dairy</option>
</select>
<ul id="fruitAndVeg">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
</ul>
<ul id="meatFridge">
  <li>Sausage</li>
  <li>Chicken</li>
</ul>
<ul id="deliCounter">
  <li>Ham</li>
  <li>Cheese</li>
</ul>
<ul id="dairy">
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Yoghurt</li>
</ul>
<ul id="other">
  <li>Sweets</li>
  <li>Chocolate</li>
</ul>
```